# How to handle error in react-query's onSuccess event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb, react-query

I have an api call made with React Query's `useMutation`. Once the call is done, I store the data in `indexedDB`. This process is done inside the `onSuccess` parameter of `useMutation`.

In firefox, the process always fails. So I need to throw an error and let the user know that this browser is not supported. But React Query doesn't catch the error anymore inside the `onSuccess` method. How to fix this? Here is the code:

```js
// the mutation
const login: AuthService["login"] = () => {
  const { mutateAsync, isLoading, error, reset, isSuccess } = useMutation( 
  (form: LoginForm) => _login(form),
    {
      onSuccess: async (user: User) => {
        await IndexedDB.saveUser(user);
      },
    }
  );

  return {
    onLogin: (form: LoginForm) => mutateAsync(form),
    loading: isLoading,
    reset: () => reset(),
    serverError: error ? error["message"] : "",
    success: isSuccess,
  };
};

// the indexedDb function (the first part, this why the naming is different):
  static createDB() {
    const request = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, 1);
    request.onupgradeneeded = (e: IDBVersionChangeEvent) => {
      const db = e.target["result"];
      return db.createObjectStore(MY_STORE, { autoIncrement: true });
    };
    request.onerror = () => { 
      throw new Error("this browser is not supported"); // error not caught
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would likely to make it part of the `mutationFn`, in your case, `_login(form)`. You can just normally `await` your mutation there and after that save to IndexedDB.